# R + dplyr: most efficient refactoring of Booleans?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a dataset of 300,000 items with 300 columns. I've been using dplyr for a lot of my dataset manipulation.

I'm importing the data as a CSV file with readr. There are quite a lot of optional boolean fields which are stored in the CSV character format as 'Y', 'N' or "". I currently import those as factors with readr.

I'm then trying to convert them to booleans. Been tri-state, I've done this as follows:

```
importedData <- dplyr::mutate(importedData,
    bar <- (foo == 'Y'),
    bar <- dplyr::if_else(
      foo,
      NA,
      bar),
    foo = NULL)
...repeated for about 30 fields.
)

importedData <- dplyr::rename(importedData,
  foo = bar)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Bonus marks for doing it in a single pass (ie so the variable is replaced in-place without the second rename call and/or so it can be phrased using tidyeval semantics).

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(colsofinterest), funs(replace(., .!= "Y", NA)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a large dataset and want to efficiently use available RAM. Here's something you could do:

```
colsOfInterest <- ("var1", "var2", "var3")

for(i in colsOfInterest){
    importedData[i] <- ifelse(is.na(importedData[i]),NA,
                              ifelse(importedData[i] == "Y", TRUE, FALSE))
    gc()
}
```

The call to `gc()` will ensure that you keep reusing the RAM that is available after each pass over a variable of interest to you. I have found that explicitly calling Garbage Collector is useful when you have RAM constraints. You are also replacing in-place instead of creating a total new set of variables, deleting old ones and renaming new to old variable names.

HTH!!

Comment: Thanks - these give some good ideas. I have already discovered that using case_when is significantly slower than a pair of if_else statements (and that the dplyr one is worth using over the base R one). Hadn't tried the idea of using the garbage collector.

Comment: Another thing that you could try is using data.tables instead of data.frames. Data.tables give quite a performance boost (adding a key to the data.table will give additional performance gain over and above this). Syntactically, data.table is not very different (for your case). If possible let me know the difference in performance when using dplyr::if_else versus base::ifelse. Thanks!!